# How to loop an array of audio files for a definite number of times? not infinite

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code snippet is working continuously and repeating the audio files non stop, tried many things like for loop but then it either plays the first audio file or the last one depending on the `.reverse()` function

```
var token = writtenNumber(21, { lang: 'ar' }).split(' ');
var playlist = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < token.length; i++) {
  playlist.push(token[i] + '.ogg')
}

console.log(playlist);

function callCustomer() {
  customerNumber.play();
  customerNumber.onended = function() {
    var audio = new Audio(),
        i = 0;

    audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
      i = ++i < playlist.length ? i : 0;
      console.log(i)
      audio.src = token[i] + '.ogg';
      audio.play();
      audio.loop = false;
    }, true);

    audio.volume = 0.3;
    audio.loop = false;
    audio.src = token[0] + '.ogg';
    audio.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: There's already a counting variable (`i`). Just add another one which is incremented when `i >= playlist.length`. And after `x` rounds remove the event handler/stop playing music.

Comment: An event callback function is executed in the global context, it means that it won't "see" the `var i` declared in `callCustomer`. On the contrary, the one here `for (var i = 0; ...` is not scoped to the for loop, like many people would think, it's global (with your current code, if the whole code is in another function, this `i` won't be seen either). The callback function will see this one which has the value of `token.length` because the loop is finished.

Comment: Just realized that even if applicable to the code, my last comment may not be relevant. After re-reading, is this code a working one you want to modify? If so, share rather the one that you tried to change and which don't work as expected, with details on why it's unexpected. In SO we can correct code if the post proves to be useful for future readers, but it's not a free coding site.